# SQL query with string prefixes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some basic query that pulls out TransactionIDs of any transaction that meet certain criteria:

```
SELECT TransactionID FROM Transaction WHERE Amount > 100
```

My application has ability to cancel transactions. In such case a new record is created in Transaction table. Such record has 'C' prefix added in front of TransactionID of original transaction and that is used as TransactionID of new record. So when transaction with TransactionID equal to "123" gets cancelled, a new record with TransactionID "C123" will get created. Both original and new record stay in Transaction table. The original record does not get modified at all. The only indication that a transaction is cancelled is presence of "C-transaction" in my table.

When I query database for certain transactions (SELECT statement listed earlier), I want to exclude all transactions that has gotten cancelled. So for each TransactionID returned, I want to make sure that no C-TransactionID exists. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: This seems like a very bad way to implement cancelling a transaction. You have now managed to violate 1NF by stuffing two values into a single column. You should either have a column IsCancelled or a Status column instead of stuffing a C to the beginning of the TransactionID. Then your query would be a lot simpler too because you only have to look at a given column, not a substring like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not exists` to get transaction id's that are not cancelled.

```
SELECT Transaction_ID
FROM Transactions t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Transactions 
                  where transaction_id like 'C%' and
                  t.transaction_id = substring(transaction_id,2,len(transaction_id))
                 )
and transaction_id not like 'C%'
```

Another way to do it using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT case when transaction_id like 'C%' then substring(transaction_id,2,len(transaction_id)) 
       else transaction_id end as transaction_id
FROM Transactions
group by case when transaction_id like 'C%' then substring(transaction_id,2,len(transaction_id)) else transaction_id end
having count(*) =1
```

Comment: where does my "Amount > 100" clause goes in such examples? Thanks, P.

Comment: You've provided a working solution to a terrible plan of action. As the commenter on the question suggested, he should make an "is_canceled" field and use that, instead of this clumsy and non performant string juggling idea. I really hope that this answer won't lead others down this dark, dead end path.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Sean couldn't be more correct, but what if this is a third part DB & App where the OP couldn't modify it's structure... then what?

Comment: @Peter it'd just be `AND Amount > 100` in the `WHERE` clause. You can add that to this answer and it'll work. If you are still confused look at my answer and you will see how you can place that as well. Both work fine--and I'd also not take Sean Lange's comments lightly if you are able to modify the applications behavior.

Comment: @scsimon - I am not able to mofidy the applications behavior. I have to admit I ended up utilizing two separate queries and just utilizing results of first query in my second query. That just came out as more clear and simple solution to implement. Anyway, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT TransactionID 
FROM Transaction 
WHERE TransactionID not in (select right(TransactionID,len(TransactionID) - 1) from Transaction where TransactionID like 'c%'
AND Amount > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of EXCEPT operator

`SELECT Name FROM Fruits
EXCEPT
SELECT Name FROM TropicalFruits`

Comment: I think you are missing a something in your second `SELECT` and where did you get the `Fruits` and `TropicalFruits` table names?

Comment: I just wanted to mention the EXCEPT operator, and the names and table names are just names out of nowhere. sorry if that confused you, but what I was going for was, select all the names from the Fruits table, assuming there is one but not the ones that are in the TropicalFruits table, so the result would be all but tropical fruits names.